# Set a PDFFormField's value with a specific font size

Tags: pdfbox

I have a very simple use-case for a filling up an acroform. I have a non-multi line text field. I would like to resize the font size to fit in the width of the text field.

The PDF spec mentions that a font size of 0 implies auto fit to width. However [PDFBox - 1419](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-1419)  & [PDFBOX-1402](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-1402) mention that this isn’t supported in pdfbox.

Hence I have some small logic to calculate the font-sizes based on the widths etc. However I’m facing problems setting the font size.

I’m seeing the behavior mentioned in [PDFBox - 1419](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-1419).

> Starts out with incorrect font size. If I click into the field, it displays correctly. Click outside the field, it reverts back to the wrong display.

Code :

```
pdfFormField.getDictionary.setString(COSName.DA, "/Helv 10 Tf 0 g”)
pdfFormField.setValue("Hello")
```

Any pointers or help would be much appreciated.

A simple example of such a PDF [is here](http://monosnap.com/file/5fxGhQSdXszX4DIoTyGguZ3ploinAC)

Comment: Pdfbox form field classes read the default appearance early.Thus, when creating the appearance stream, the former DA value most likely is used.

Comment: mkl: Thanks! Not sure then how to specify the font size when setting the value. In my case, the font-size depends on the value.

Comment: I think i need to somehow regenerate the appearance stream for the pdf form field.

Comment: After setting the default appearance, instantiate the form field object anew. Then set the field value using this new object. E.g. look at [this answer to *How to set the text of a PDTextbox to a color?*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22082301/1729265); here the existing **DA** value of a text field is changed to contain a color setting operation before the field value is set.

Comment: Great! I'll make it an answer in its own right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pdfbox form field classes read the default appearance into a member variable early in their life-cycle and don't follow-up to changes in the form field dictionary they are based on. Thus, when creating the appearance stream during `pdfFormField.setValue("Hello")`, the former **DA** value is used.

*After setting the default appearance, therefore, you have to instantiate the form field object anew. Then set the field value using this new object.*

For sample code look at [this answer to *How to set the text of a PDTextbox to a color?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22082301/1729265); here the existing **DA** value of a text field is changed to contain a color setting operation before the field value is set.